# How to corresponding li tag related data only

Tags: jquery

I have `<ul>` tag with two `<li>` options , on click of each i need to show corresponding data related to that only

This is my program

```
<div id="divforhistoricresults" class="classhistoricaldataresults">
   <div class="list-container-2">
      <ul class="tabs-2 clearfix">
         <li><a href="#one">Data</a></li>
         <li><a href="#two">Chart</a></li>
      </ul>
   </div>
   <div class="tab-container-2">
      <table id="one" class="tab-content-1 table table-striped">  
      </table>
      <table id="two" class="tab-content-1 table table-striped">                        
      </table>
   </div>
</div>


$(document).ready(function() {});
$("ul.tabs-2 li").click(function()
{
    var tabclicked = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
    if (tabclicked === '#one')
    {
        var onehtml = '<thead><th>ONE</th>';
        $("#one").html(onehtml);
     //   $("#two").hide();
    }
    else if (tabclicked === '#two')
    {
        var twohtml = '<thead><th>TWO</th>';
        $("#two").html(twohtml);
      //  $("#one").hide();
    }
});
```

The issue i am facing is that both are being visible?? and is it possible to make the table `id="one"` to be shown by default ??

Could you please tell me how to resolve the above issue

this is my fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/jq4f69cz/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jq4f69cz/6/)**.

Add `show()` method before appending html and uncomment `hide()` method :

```
 $("#one").show().html(onehtml);
 $("#two").show().html(onehtml);
```

To show one as default add following line after your event :

```
$('ul.tabs-2 li:eq(0)').click();
```

Hope this helps.

---

```js
$("ul.tabs-2 li").click(function()
{
 var tabclicked = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
 if (tabclicked === '#one')
 {
     var onehtml = '<thead><th>ONE</th>';
     $("#one").show().html(onehtml);
            $("#two").hide();
 }
 else if (tabclicked === '#two')
 {
     var twohtml = '<thead><th>TWO</th>';
     $("#two").show().html(twohtml);
            $("#one").hide();
 }
});

$('ul.tabs-2 li:eq(0)').click();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divforhistoricresults" class="classhistoricaldataresults">
   <div class="list-container-2">
      <ul class="tabs-2 clearfix">
         <li><a href="#one">Data</a></li>
         <li><a href="#two">Chart</a></li>
      </ul>
   </div>
   <div class="tab-container-2">
      <table id="one" class="tab-content-1 table table-striped">  
      </table>
      <table id="two" class="tab-content-1 table table-striped">                        
      </table>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot , is it possible to show default as ONE ??

Comment: You're welcome, yes possible check my updated answer.